# How to wait for rows to load with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to use protractor to select a row, count rows, etc. This doesn't seem to be working:

```
var GridTestUtils = require('./gridObjectTestUtils.spec.js');

var GridTestObj = new GridTestUtils('exampleGrid');
var Grid = GridTestObj.getGrid();

browser.wait(function(){

    return Grid.isPresent();

}, 1000).then(function(){

    GridTestObj.expectRowCount( 25 );

});
```

It seems as though it's trying to find the rows before they're loaded. The test keeps failing with 'Expected 0 to equal 25'.

I can get it to work if I use `browser.sleep` but there has to be a better solution than that.

How do I tell protractor to wait for Angular ui-grid to load completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that with [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and a *custom Expected Condition*:

```
var rows = Grid.element( by.css('.ui-grid-render-container-body')).all( by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index') );

browser.wait(function () {
    return rows.count().then(function (countValue) { 
        return countValue > 0;
    });
}, 5000);
```

In this case, `protractor` would execute the function passed into `browser.wait()` continuously until it evaluates to true or the timeout happens (in 5 seconds).

Comment: It's not full proof though as it will trigger just when it finds first row and if the table has hundreds of rows and that too dynamic, just wonder how it could be improvised.